# Error with urllib3 and the python-telegram-bot API

Tags: python-3.x, python-telegram-bot

when i try to run my script (my telegram bot) the following appears in terminal:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/python_telegram_bot-12.4.2- 
py3.7.egg/telegram/utils/request.py:47: UserWarning: python-telegram-bot is using upstream urllib3. 
This is allowed but not supported by python-telegram-bot maintainers.
```

what I do?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Originally, `python-telegram-bot` only shipped with a vendored version of `urllib3` [that was created to fix a bug that could not be fixed upstream.](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/issues/533)

To allow `python-telegram-bot` to be shipped as part of Linux distributions, the dependency on the vendored `urllib3` [has been made optional](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/issues/1568), allowing `python-telegram-bot` to work with the standard `urllib3`.

So the message you're seeing is expected behavior if you installed `python-telegram-bot` through your distribution's packet manager. If your bot works fine, you don't have to change anything.